# Where can I find function source codes in a .zip R package?

Tags: r, package

I'd like to use package **CentiServer** in R. However, I'm getting the same error with different R versions (3.3.3 and 3.1.1):

> Warning: unable to access index for repository
>   https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/windows/contrib/3.1 Warning message:
>   package ‘CentiServer’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)

This post is a great source, still, these steps couldn't help me to find a solution: [How should I deal with "package 'xxx' is not available (for R version x.y.z)" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25721884/how-should-i-deal-with-package-xxx-is-not-available-for-r-version-x-y-z-wa)

Since I cannot install the package, I started to think about that it could be easier to just find the source codes of some useful functions in the [.zip file](http://www.centiserver.org/?q1=rpackage). Where can I find those in the .zip file?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: here: https://github.com/cran/centiserve/tree/master/R

Comment: you should update R to the last version